# Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution - when I do not use it as a bool

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

That is the issue I am getting, but I don't use it as a bool anywhere. Or at least not that I can see. I have read similar questions, they were resolved because there was in fact an instance where it is being treated as a bool. However, I have not used it as a bool.

Functions:

```
def compile_cnn(model, loss = None, optimizer = None):

    # Compile the CNN using the specified loss function
    model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer)

    # return the compiled model
    return model
```

Custom Keras Loss functions:

```
def contrastive_loss(label, embedding, margin = 0.4):

    # Assign the label
    y = label

    # Assign the embeddings
    p1 = embedding[0]
    p2 = embedding[1]

    # Get the euclean distance    
    d = tf.norm(p1 - p2, axis=-1)

    if y == 0:
        return (1/2) * math.sqrt(d)
    else:
        return (1/2) * math.sqrt(max(0, (margin-d)))
```

Calling Code:

```
# We use Adam as optimizer
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam() 

# Compile the model with the contrastive loss function
cont_loss_model = compile_cnn(model, contrastive_loss, optimizer)
```

Here is the full error message as requested.

```
 C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Users\User\Documents\Uni\2020\IFN680\Assignment 2\SiameseNetwork.py:88 contrastive_loss  *
        return (1/2) * tf.math.sqrt(max(0, (margin-d)))
    C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:877 __bool__  **
        self._disallow_bool_casting()
    C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:486 _disallow_bool_casting
        self._disallow_when_autograph_enabled(
    C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:472 _disallow_when_autograph_enabled
        raise errors.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError(

    OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback of the error message. It probably explains exactly why the value is being used as a bool, even if you didn't expect your code to have that effect. As is, we can't even tell which thing in your program is the tensor it's complaining about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by adding `@tf.function` to the custom loss function:

```
@tf.function
def contrastive_loss(label, embedding, margin = 0.4):
```